# Primes $p$ in which $3$ is a primitive root modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I want to show that if $3$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if $p$ is a prime of the form $2^n+1$ for some $n>1$.

First, I wrote $3^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$. Then writing it as $(1+2)^{p-1}$, we see that $p| 2+ \dots 2^{p-1} =2^p - 2$ and I stuck at this point.

Also, by a theorem we can see that $3 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. I wrote $3 \equiv n^2 \mod p$ but that is not helpful too.

So, how can I prove this theorem?

Comment: Primitive roots can't be quadratic residues.

Comment: What do you know about primes of the form $2^n+1$?

Comment: $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $5$ or mod $17$.

Comment: Worth remarking:  by a simple count, all the non-squares mod a Fermat prime are primitive roots.  Hence, showing that $3$ isn't a square proves it's a primitive root.